# SSIS Package Load Error

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

One of the package runs through a job daily at 8:00. It truncates and loads data from Oracle and populates table on SQL Server. The package always runs to success but the table is empty. We looked into the Query and everything seems fine. Any possible theories ?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your logging tell you is going on?  If you don't have enough logging to debug the problem, you need more logging.  Having random folks on the internet guess at the problem is probably not going to be particularly useful.

Comment: We found out the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue when inserting to Oracle. The problem was we were using general OLE DB provider. When I changed it to dedicated Oracle provider it started to return errors. Please check if you use Oracle provider for selecting your data and MS provider when inserting to MSSQL.